# PickerView into a collection view Cell not displayed swift

Tags: swift, pickerview

I have a problem with an UIPickerView into a CollectionViewCell.
The Picker has the viewController as delegate and datasource, but the object instance is into the redefinition of the CollectionViewCell.

The view controller is UIPickerViewDelegate and UIPickerViewDataSource and contains the array with the data to be displayed in the picker.

If the data are stored in the array during the creation of the collectionViewCell the picker is displayed. When i change data of the array the picker disappears.

How could it be possible ?

Comment: Can you show your code? Probably you need call `reloadAllComponents()` when you change your array

Comment: the problem was on a string format 
and also in reloadAllComponents() :)
thanks